# MVC: Allow multiple click of the same button

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

Is it possible to allow multiple clicks on a sigle submit button of a form? I have a form where I want to perform an action on the first submission (first click) and a different action on the second submission (second click).

I am basically using ajax to populate a div in the form during the first submission and I want to  submit the form on the second click.

I have tried to put by button in the div to by updated, and after the first click, I update update the div and re-creating the button in the updated div. But if I use this method, how can I set the action method of the newly created button in my controller method for Ajax?
My controller method returns something like

`return Content( mystring + <input type='button' value='continue submission'/>`

if i use this approach, how do I set the action method of the buttton, or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a little weird but I can tell you how to do this. Take an input type="submit" and make it hidden. Have a variable as var flag = false; When user first clicks you input type="button" call a function and do your stuff and make sure to make the flag=true; In the function itself check if flag=true; the trigger the event of your input type="submit".
Like as follows:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="perfromAction()" value="submit"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn2" value="submit" style="display:none"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flag=false;
function performAction()
{
if(flag){
  $("#btn2").trigger("click");
}
else{
 //do processing 
 flag=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two buttons with JavaScript:

Button 1 is shown initially. On click, it hides itself, shows button 2, and performs your action 1.

Button 2 is hidden initially. It is unhidden by button 1 and on click, it performs your second action.